# How to run a PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

How do I run a PowerShell script?

- I have a script named myscript.ps1
- I have all the necessary frameworks installed
- I set that [execution policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635/why-dont-my-powershell-scripts-run) thing
- I have followed the instructions on [this MSDN help page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx)
  and am trying to run it like so:
  `powershell.exe 'C:\my_path\yada_yada\run_import_script.ps1'` (with or without `--noexit`)

which returns exactly nothing, except that the file name is output.

No error, no message, nothing. Oh, when I add `-noexit`, the same thing happens, but I remain within PowerShell and have to exit manually.

The .ps1 file is supposed to run a program and return the error level dependent on that program's output. But I'm quite sure I'm not even getting there yet.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Start the `powershell` as you would have started `cmd`. Now you can execute the `myscript.ps1` script as any executable there in (in powershell window), i.e. `.\myscript.ps1`

Comment: The MSDN/Technet URL now redirects to a page saying *"The Windows PowerShell 1.0 Owner’s Manual has been retired. For the most up-to-date Windows PowerShell content, go to Using Windows PowerShell."* I'll try to replace it with a valid URL if I have time this afternoon.

Answer (score 1031, accepted):

Prerequisites:

- You need to be able to run PowerShell as an administrator
- You need to set your PowerShell execution policy to a permissive value or be able to bypass it

Steps:

1. Launch Windows PowerShell as an Administrator, and wait for the `PS>` prompt to appear
2. Navigate within PowerShell to the directory where the script lives:

   ```
   PS> cd C:\my_path\yada_yada\ (enter)
   ```
3. Execute the script:

   ```
   PS> .\run_import_script.ps1 (enter)
   ```

Or: you can run the PowerShell script from the Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) like this:

```
powershell -noexit "& ""C:\my_path\yada_yada\run_import_script.ps1""" (enter)
```

according to [*Invoking a PowerShell script from cmd.exe (or Start | Run)*](http://poshoholic.com/2007/09/27/invoking-a-powershell-script-from-cmdexe-or-start-run/) by Kirk Munro.

Or you could even [run your PowerShell script asynchronously from your C# application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/AsyncPowerShell.aspx).

Comment: This indeed works, but I need to do this from within a batch file. Obviously, my way of calling `powershell.exe` and then the script file is somehow screwed up. Do you have any idea how to modify it?

Comment: Your blog post link did it. I have to use `powershell -noexit "& "C:\yada_yada\run_import_script.ps1"` (notice the *three* double quotes) I don't really understand why, but at this point, I don't really care :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly does the `"&` do?

Comment: According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx, the '&' is for "If you actually want to execute that string value (that is, if you want to run the script whose path is enclosed in double quotes) you need to preface the path with the Call operator (the ampersand)."

Comment: Just use the command `powershell c:\mypath\yadayada\myimportantscript.ps1` if your path and file name have no spaces in it but if you put quotes around it powershell will try and interpret the parameter as a string of powershell commands.

Answer (score 321):

If you are on PowerShell 2.0, use PowerShell.exe's `-File` parameter to invoke a script from another environment, like cmd.exe. For example:

```
Powershell.exe -File C:\my_path\yada_yada\run_import_script.ps1
```

Comment: Is there a way to add parameters to such an invocation?

Comment: You should just be able to trail the args after the script file path. From the PowerShell.exe usage - [-File <filePath> <args>]

Comment: "cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" fo r more details."

Comment: If you haven't enabled PowerShell script execution on your system add the parameter `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`

Comment: FYI this also works for PowerShell 1.0 in my experience (Windows 2012 Server)

Answer (score 240):

If you want to run a script without modifying the default script execution policy, you can use the *bypass* switch when launching **Windows PowerShell**.

```
powershell [-noexit] -executionpolicy bypass -File <Filename>
```

Comment: Also, include the `-nologo` option to get rid of the startup banner

Answer (score 121):

In a command prompt type:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File .\Test.ps1
```

NOTE:  Here `Test.ps1` is the PowerShell script.

Comment: This should be executed in a powershell as `powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File .\Test.ps1` assuming you current working directory contains Test.ps1

Answer (score 38):

I've had the same problem, and I tried and tried... Finally I used:

```
powershell.exe -noexit "& 'c:\Data\ScheduledScripts\ShutdownVM.ps1'"
```

And put this line in a batch-file, and this works.

Answer (score 27):

If you only have **PowerShell 1.0**, this seems to do the trick well enough:

```
powershell -command - < c:\mypath\myscript.ps1
```

It pipes the script file to the PowerShell command line.

Comment: Useful trick when security policies don't allow script execution.

Answer (score 25):

Pretty easy. Right click the .ps1 file in Windows and in the shell menu click on *Run with PowerShell*.

Comment: This works to quickly run a script without having to enable the execution of scripts with execution policy. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

1. Open PowerShell in administrator mode
2. Run: `set-executionpolicy unrestricted`
3. Open a regular PowerShell window and run your script.

I found this solution following the link that was given as part of the error message: *[About Execution Policies](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170)*

Make sure to run `set-ExecutionPolicy default` once you're done, or you will be exposed to security risks.

Answer (score 15):

If your script is named with the `.ps1` extension and you're in a PowerShell window, you just run `./myscript.ps1` (assuming the file is in your working directory).

This is true for me anyway on Windows 10 with PowerShell version 5.1 anyway, and I don't think I've done anything to make it possible.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: it absolutely answers the question:  how do I run a powershell script? answer:  startup powershell console, then execute the script.   easy.  simple.  Works on Linux also.

Comment: This absolutely answers the question, and was exactly what I was looking for. as `myscript.ps1` did not work, threw an error, but with `./` it's executing.

Comment: But what if script has no suffix?

Answer (score 12):

Using cmd (BAT) file:

```
@echo off
color 1F
echo.

C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "PrepareEnvironment.ps1"

:EOF
echo Waiting seconds
timeout /t 10 /nobreak > NUL
```

If you need **run as administrator**:

1. Make a shortcut pointed to the command prompt (I named it
   Administrative Command Prompt)
2. Open the shortcut's properties and go to the Compatibility tab
3. Under the Privilege Level section, make sure the checkbox next to "Run this program as an administrator" is checked

Answer (score 12):

An easy way is to use [PowerShell ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx), open script, run and invoke your script, function...

[image]

Answer (score 12):

In case you want to run a PowerShell script with Windows Task Scheduler, please follow the steps below:

1. Create a task
2. Set `Program/Script` to `Powershell.exe`
3. Set `Arguments` to `-File "C:\xxx.ps1"`

It's from another answer, *[How do I execute a PowerShell script automatically using Windows task scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953926/how-to-execute-a-powershell-script-automatically-using-windows-task-scheduler/23954618#23954618)*.

Answer (score 9):

- Give the path of the script, that is, path setting by cmd:

  `$> . c:\program file\prog.ps1`
- Run the entry point function of PowerShell:

  For example, `$> add or entry_func or main`

Comment: Running your commands from a cmd prompt:
`>$ . c:\program file\prog.ps1
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`
and
`>$ add or entry_func or main
'add' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 4):

You can run from cmd like this:

```
type "script_path" | powershell.exe -c -
```

Answer (score 4):

I've just found the method what Microsoft do when we right click on a `ps1` script and click on "Run with PowerShell" :

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\MYSCRIPT.ps1'"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-File` parameter in front of the filename. The quotes make PowerShell think it is a string of commands.

Answer (score 1):

With the appropriate execution policy, you should just be able to call the file directly and Windows will associate it with PowerShell

```
C:\my_path\yada_yada\run_import_script.ps1
```

That does not do so well with arguments. The real answer to your question is that you are missing the `&` to say "execute this"

```
powershell.exe '& C:\my_path\yada_yada\run_import_script.ps1'
```