# How to execute PowerShell commands from a batch file?

Tags: powershell, command-line, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I have a PowerShell script to add a website to a Trusted Sites in Internet Explorer:

```
set-location "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set-location ZoneMap\Domains
new-item TESTSERVERNAME
set-location TESTSERVERNAME
new-itemproperty . -Name http -Value 2 -Type DWORD
```

I want to execute these PowerShell commands from a batch file. It seems simple when I have to run a single command, **BUT** in this case I have a sequence of related commands. I want to avoid creating a separate file for the PS script to be called from the batch - everything must be in the batch file.

The question is: How to execute PowerShell commands (or statements) from a batch file?

Comment: Also see ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script

Answer (score 124, accepted):

This is what the code would look like in a batch file(tested, works):

```
powershell -Command "& {set-location 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings'; set-location ZoneMap\Domains; new-item SERVERNAME; set-location SERVERNAME; new-itemproperty . -Name http -Value 2 -Type DWORD;}"
```

Based on the information from:

http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/powershell-script-in-a-bat-file/

Comment: how I can split long lines ? lines similar to your example.

Comment: @JuanPablo Sorry for VERY late reply but only today made a commitment to review my stackoverflow usage and be more active. Did you get this answered?

Comment: Is it possible to pass multiple .ps1 files ?

Comment: Can you give an example? Sounds like another question.

Comment: for fun, `#!/bin/bash` `powershell <<<'run this string'` works, but its so. slow.

Answer (score 11):

This solution is similar to walid2mi (thank you for inspiration), but allows the standard console input by the Read-Host cmdlet.

**pros:**

- can be run like standard .cmd file
- only one file for batch and powershell script
- powershell script may be multi-line (easy to read script)
- allows the standard console input (use the Read-Host cmdlet by standard way)

**cons:**

- requires powershell version 2.0+

Commented and runable example of **batch-ps-script.cmd**:

```
<# : Begin batch (batch script is in commentary of powershell v2.0+)
@echo off
: Use local variables
setlocal
: Change current directory to script location - useful for including .ps1 files
cd %~dp0
: Invoke this file as powershell expression
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -Command "Invoke-Expression $([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('%~f0'))"
: Restore environment variables present before setlocal and restore current directory
endlocal
: End batch - go to end of file
goto:eof
#>
# here start your powershell script

# example: include another .ps1 scripts (commented, for quick copy-paste and test run)
#. ".\anotherScript.ps1"

# example: standard input from console
$variableInput = Read-Host "Continue? [Y/N]"
if ($variableInput -ne "Y") {
    Write-Host "Exit script..."
    break
}

# example: call standard powershell command
Get-Item .
```

Snippet for .cmd file:

```
<# : batch script
@echo off
setlocal
cd %~dp0
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -Command "Invoke-Expression $([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('%~f0'))"
endlocal
goto:eof
#>
# here write your powershell commands...
```

Comment: Usage note: there are some edge cases where `cd %~dp0` won't work, and this style of invocation will set `$PSScriptRoot` to null, because we're running as a series of commands instead of as a script. I've dropped the `cd %~dp0` and changed the invoked expression to `$($ScriptHome = '%~dp0'; [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('%~dpf0'))` to handle this.

Comment: Do I include the **#** in my powershell commands?

Comment: @JustinGoldberg - <# comment block for powershell #> - in this comment block is  .bat/.cmd commands for powershell run, and after that comment block you can use any powershell syntax with a # :)

Answer (score 10):

Type in cmd.exe `Powershell -Help` and see the examples.

Answer (score 6):

**untested.cmd**

```
;@echo off
;Findstr -rbv ; %0 | powershell -c - 
;goto:sCode

set-location "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set-location ZoneMap\Domains
new-item TESTSERVERNAME
set-location TESTSERVERNAME
new-itemproperty . -Name http -Value 2 -Type DWORD

;:sCode 
;echo done
;pause & goto :eof
```

Answer (score 4):

When calling multiline PowerShell statements from a batch file, end each line with a caret, except the last line. You don't have to have the extra spacing at the beginning of the line, that's my convention.

```
PowerShell set-location "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^
           set-location ZoneMap\Domains ^
           new-item TESTSERVERNAME ^
           set-location TESTSERVERNAME ^
           new-itemproperty . -Name http -Value 2 -Type DWORD
```

If you are piping into a cmdlet like Select-Object, you need to terminate with a semicolon to end the command, otherwise it will include the next line.

```
Powershell $disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter """"DeviceID='D:'"""" ^| Select-Object Freespace; ^
           Exit ([math]::truncate($disk.freespace / 1GB))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the possibility to put a powershell script into a batch file, I found this thread. The idea of walid2mi did not worked 100% for my script. But via a temporary file, containing the script it worked out. Here is the skeleton of the batch file:

```
;@echo off
;setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
;rem make from X.bat a X.ps1 by removing all lines starting with ';' 
;Findstr -rbv "^[;]" %0 > %~dpn0.ps1 
;powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File %~dpn0.ps1 %*
;del %~dpn0.ps1
;endlocal
;goto :EOF
;rem Here start your power shell script.
param(
    ,[switch]$help
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any answers to work, but adding [@Hassan Voyeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037167/12501297)'s `-Command` and `;`'s in tandem with [@Ed Palmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67125754/12501297)'s formatting made it work:

```
powershell -Command ^
More? set-location "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"; ^
More? set-location ZoneMap\Domains; ^
More? new-item TESTSERVERNAME; ^
More? set-location TESTSERVERNAME; ^
More? new-itemproperty . -Name http -Value 2 -Type DWORD
```

Here, `;` tells powershell.exe being called that the current command-line ends there and more command-lines can be specified further while `^` tells CMD (for the sake of simplicity; it's actually called "Windows Script Host") that there may be more string input on the next line. From our perspective, CMD parses multiple command-lines into one command-line via [CR/LF line-endings escape character `^`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) so that powershell.exe sees the one-line command-line `-Command set-location ...; set-location ...; ...` instead.

- If you want to specify any `powershell` parameters, do so before `-Command` since powershell.exe interprets command-lines subsequent to `-Command` as `-Command`'s single code-block argument. Using curly-braces to explicitly delimit the code block like `-Command {set-location ...; ...}` doesn't allow specifying `powershell` parameters afterward, e.g. `-Command {...} -NoExit`, either.
- In this formatting, don't use `"` to delimit `-Command`'s argument like [@Hassan Voyeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037167/12501297)'s since CMD interprets `^` inside unclosed `"` as a literal caret character.
- Using `^` as the first character on any line after the first line will also make CMD interpret it as a literal caret character. Use a whitespace   before one to semantically designate an empty line instead.
- If you want to include a comment between code, use PowerShell's block-comment `<# .. #>` (PowerShell's in-line comment `#` which denotes all subsequent characters as part of its comment can't be escaped since, again, `^` parses multiple command-lines into one command-line.) However, without `"` as in [@Hassan Voyeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037167/12501297)'s to encapsulate `<` and `>`, CMD will parse them as [I/O redirection operators](https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/io-redirection-and-pipes.html) which we can [escape by using a prefixing-caret](https://www.knowledgewalls.com/johnpeter/books/msdos-commands/how-to-escape-characters-in-string-using-ms-dos-commands) like `^<# COMMENT GOES HERE #^>`. If you insert a block-comment on an empty line, `^` will become the first character of the line and will be interpreted as a literal caret character so we work around that like earlier by inserting a prefixing whitespace to get:

  ```
  ⋮
  More? COMMAND ARG1 ARG2 ...; ^<# IN-LINE BLOCK COMMENT #^> ^
  More?  ^<# SEPARATE-LINE BLOCK COMMENT #^> ^
  More? COMMAND ARG1 ARG2 ...;^<# NO PREFIXING/SUFFIXING SPACES REQUIRED #^>^
  ⋮
  ```
- To escape characters in arguments, use [PowerShell's escape character backtick/grave-accent `` ` ``](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html). Since backticks aren't one of [its escape characters (`^` for I/O redirection operators, `\` for double-quotes, `%` for percent)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), CMD won't consume backticks.

  - If your arguments contains spaces but not escape characters, you can use single-quotes to delimit the argument. CMD will parse it as multiple arguments still since the spaces aren't delimited but PowerShell will correctly piece it back together with spaces reattached.
  - If your arguments contains escape characters, you can use double-quotes encapsulating CMD-escaped double-quotes or the other way around to commands. The unescaped double-quotes tell CMD that special characters within, e.g. spaces, mustn't be treated as argument separators while CMD-escaped double-quotes pass onto and are parsed by PowerShell as normal double-quotes. The escape character for double-quotes is `\`. ([Quoting/Escaping 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20160622100504/windowsinspired.com/understanding-the-command-line-string-and-arguments-received-by-a-windows-program/)/[2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160708183935/http://www.windowsinspired.com/how-a-windows-programs-splits-its-command-line-into-individual-arguments/)) For instance:

  ```
  More? write-output 'there are spaces here'; ^
  More? write-output "\"new line`r`nhere\""; ^
  More? write-output \""also`r`nhere"\"; ^
  ```

  will result in:

  ```
  there are spaces here
  new line
  here
  also
  here
  ```