# How to call a Powershell file from a batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I want to call a simple Powershell script file that should return either 0 or 1 upon the ps script failure or pass respectively,  from a batch file . And based upon the return value, I want to continue further or quit.

The following illustrates what I have tried out:

startup.bat:-

```
@ECHO OFF
SET x = powershell C:\Users\saravind\Desktop\pingping.ps1
if "%x%" == 1 then (
    doSomething1
    ECHO Ran project 1
)
```

pingping.ps1:-

```
$someIP = '192.168.173.299'
$result = $true
try { Test-Connection $someIP -Source localhost -ErrorAction Stop }
catch { $result = $false }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that on the execution of pingping.ps1 if it can successfully ping the '192.168.173.299', it should return some value, say 1 to the batch file from which it was being called. And if the ping fails, it should return 0 so that the batch file will not proceed with 'doSomething'
Eventhough the pingping fails, it proceeds with doSomething with my code. What's wrong with my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a duplicate question.
Check that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180572/execute-powershell-script-inside-batch-file

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate of that. There he say's the ps1 file does exist. And he's just tryin to execute a powershell statement.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932291/calling-powershell-cmdlets-from-windows-batch-file

Comment: Aplogies, I am not that clear whether the call SET x = powershell C:\Users\saravind\Desktop\pingping.ps1 can be altered to return something. I'm getting the value of as "" always. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Why don't you try something like:
powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Users\saravind\Desktop\pingping.ps1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The followign works for me, I used 0 to indicate the powershell script succeeded and 1 for error happened.

startup.bat:

```
@echo off
powershell C:\Users\saravind\Desktop\pingping.ps1

if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    doSomething1
    ECHO Ran project 1
)
```

pingping.ps1:

```
$someIP = '192.168.173.299'
try {
    Test-Connection $someIP -Source localhost -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    exit 1
}
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not test if the 'ping' have success?

your ps1 file should be:

```
$someIP = '192.168.173.299'
it ( Test-Connection $someIP )
{ 1 }
Else
{ 0 }
```

your batch file should be:

```
@echo off
FOR /f  %%i IN ('powershell -noprofile C:\Users\saravind\Desktop\pingping.ps1') DO set x=%%i
if "%x%" == 1 (
doSomething1
@echo  Ran project 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @C.B, but in both the cases(for 1 & o), the doSomething is getting executed.

Comment: @user2234700 oops.. remove the `then` after the if statment.. have fixed it in my answer.. try now.