# Strange redirect in Batch/Powershell polyglot

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

While attempting to rewrite a batch file, I was looking into the possibility of using powershell. The main issue that I had with it was that `.ps1` files aren't executable by default. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41986771/1942154), which I'll copy below, but I'm very confused about the syntax on the first line:

```
<# : batch script
@echo off
setlocal
cd %~dp0
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -Command "Invoke-Expression $([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('%~f0'))"
endlocal
goto:eof
#>
# here write your powershell commands...
```

Here's what I know from testing:

- The space between `<#` and `:` is required, though there can be multiple.
- It can also have a number 0-9 beforehand, such as `3<# :`, which makes me suspect that there's some weirdness involving redirects and labels.
- The text after the colon is ignored and not necessary
- If I add a command before it, such as `git <# : batch script`, the shell shows that it tried to evaluate `git  : batch script 0<#` and can't find the file specified
- Changing the `#` to a valid filename makes the complaint go away (naturally)
- Attempting to run the line in an interactive session actually causes it to complain about not being able to find the file specified, but running it from a script (even if it's the only line in the `.cmd` file) silently succeeds

That last bullet is the part I'm trying to figure out. What's different about the environments? My understanding was that part of the issue was that running a bat file is parsed as if each line were manually entered. Why doesn't it complain about `#` being an invalid file when called via a script?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't a multiline comment, used to show the "old" batch-file code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*"...running a bat file is parsed as if each line were manually entered."*

No, parser rules are sometimes different between command line and batch file and in this case the difference is critical.

It complains about `#` being an invalid file in command line, and not in batch file, because the `<# :` construct is (to the batch parser) just a redirected **label**. The same kind of label you use in `goto :label` or `call :label`.

That means that the redirection, that is not executed in batch file as the "command" associated to the redirection is a label, is executed in command line as you can not have a label in a command line.

Comment: Is there any documentation showing this? I'm still not entirely sure why the difference exists, since it appears that I can create labels in the interactive session?

Comment: @MattSoucy, If you use something like `:label` from command line, you will not have a label (you can not `goto` or `call` to it), but a *null command* (I have to give it a name) as far as the first non blank/non delimiter character is a colon. You can use `:label <file` (with `file` existing or not) and it will "work" (null command), but if you write `<file :label` (with `file` existing) the redirection changes the parsing and you will get an error as `:label` can not be handled as a command. You only have *labels* inside batch files.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that you need a valid construct for both, powershell and also batch.
For powershell only th `<#` is important to open a multiline comment.

For batch you need something that will be valid code but is invisible inspite of the `echo on` state.
Therefore a colon is perfect in this situation, as label lines will not be shown, even with `echo on`.

You can see the result of the parser, when you replace the colon with `REM`.

```
<# REM Batch script
```

Output:

```
c:\Temp>REM batch script 0<#
```

The `#` is a valid filename, but the file itself is never accesed.