# Converting web app files to UTF-8 for Windows 8 Apps

Tags: windows-8, utf-8

It seems like I get the same UTF-8 error every time I submit a Windows 8 app.

Is there a faster way to convert a batch of files to be UTF-8 formatted?

Comment: What is the actual error message?  Why are you not creating your files in UTF-8 to begin with?

Comment: I'm using an editor that doesn't have that setting.

Comment: Notepad and Visual Studio have an option to save a file as UTF-8 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PowerShell script below to convert all files in a directory to UTF-8.

```
$files = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles("C:\temp\files")
foreach($file in $files) 
{     
    $content = get-content -path $file
    $content | out-file $file -encoding utf8    
}
```

You should be able to run the script above using PowerShell ISE or follow this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script).