# Powershell - Passing a folder with a space to a script block

Tags: powershell

I am using the following code to call a script with a time out:

```
function getHDriveSize($usersHomeDirectory) {
  $timeOutSeconds = 600

  $code = {
    & powershell.exe $args[0] -Path $args[1]
  }

  $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code -ArgumentList $script:getHDriveSizePath, $usersHomeDirectory

  if (Wait-Job $job -Timeout $timeOutSeconds) {
    Receive-Job $job
  } else {
    'Timed Out'
  }
}
```

However when `$script:getHDriveSizePath` has a space in it, I get the following error:

```
The term 'H:\FolderNameBeforeSpace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,...
```

I have tried using `"'$($args[0])'"` (with an escape character before the single quotes) instead of `$args[0]` but then I get this error:

```
Unexpected token '-Path' in expression or statement.
```

The script works fine if `$script:getHDriveSizePath` contains no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$script:getHDriveSizePath` holds the path to a PS1 script, you should change

```
& powershell.exe $args[0] -Path $args[1]
```

to

```
& powershell.exe -File $args[0] -Path $args[1]
```

If you don't specify the `-File` argument, PowerShell will assume `$args[0]` is a PowerShell command. Alternatively, you can do it like:

```
& powershell.exe "& '$($args[0])'" -Path $args[1]
```

This is the same issue as discussed here: [How to run a PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script). HTH.