# How to create a bat file for audio name and length

Tags: batch-file

I am completely new to bat files. I have a folder with several thousand audio files. I would like to "export" the name and length of each and save them in a single text file. It seems simple, but I've struggled for hours just trying to get started. Can someone please help?! Thank you!!!!

Comment: By 'length', do you mean file size in bytes, or audio duration?

Comment: By length I mean audio duration. In my folder view, that's how the duration is labeled.... 'Length'

Comment: There's no native batch command that can read audio file metadata. You'll need a third-party program that has a command line interface, like MediaInfo.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a PowerShell script that you can use to print MP3 filenames and audio duration. Redirect the output to a file as needed.

```
$path = 'C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\'

Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.mp3 -name | Foreach-Object {
    $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
    $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($path)
    $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($_)

    write-host $_ $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27);
}
```

And here's info on [how to run PowerShell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script).