# Search for a xml file and replace a string inside it

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to create a batch file in Windows 7 to help me remove Skype Ads.

Here's what I've come with so far:

```
@echo off

echo Editing '%WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts' file
echo 127.0.0.1       apps.skype.com >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
echo 127.0.0.1       g.msn.com >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts

echo Editing '%APPDATA%\Skype' config
powershell -Command "(Get-ChildItem %APPDATA%\Skype -Filter "config.xml" -Recurse) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '<AdvertPlaceholder>1</AdvertPlaceholder>', '<AdvertPlaceholder>0</AdvertPlaceholder>' } | Set-Content $_"

ipconfig /flushdns

pause
```

The powershell command throws me an error:

```
Editing 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Skype' config
Set-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:218
+ (Get-ChildItem C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Skype -Filter config.xml -Recurse) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '<AdvertPlaceholder>1</AdvertPlaceholder>
', '<AdvertPlaceholder>0</AdvertPlaceholder>' } | Set-Content <<<<  $_
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBinding
   ValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I Set-Content to a file found by Get-ChildItem? If you have another approach, I'd like to hear it too. Much appreciated.

***EDIT:***

Here's what I ended up using:

```
@echo off

echo Editing '%WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts' file
echo 127.0.0.1       apps.skype.com >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
echo 127.0.0.1       g.msn.com >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts

echo Editing '%APPDATA%\Skype' config
powershell -noprofile -c "$files = Get-ChildItem $env:AppData\Skype -Recurse config.xml; foreach($file in $files) { (Get-Content $file.fullname) -replace '<(AdvertPlaceholder)>1</\1>', '<$1>0</$1>' | Set-Content $file.fullname }"

ipconfig /flushdns

echo Done. Please restart Skype for changes to take effect.

pause
```

Confirmed working at the time of this post.

Comment: Set-Content requires a filename....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd recommend doing it *all* in PowerShell, which ultimately simplifies matters:
The complexity of dealing with 2 very different environments aside, invoking PowerShell commands with `powershell -command` and a command string containing the command to execute introduces quoting complexities that can be tricky to resolve.

Second, your issue is that your pipeline tries to do *2 disparate* things at once:

- pass a file's *path* through
- while also transforming that file's *content*.

Your attempt muddles the two task: it passes in file objects (that resolve to their *paths* in a string context), then mistakenly treats them as if they were their *contents*, then magically expects the modified contents to turn back into file objects (paths) telling `Set-Content` what files to write back to.

While it *is* possible to do this with a single pipeline, it would be virtually unreadable, so I recommend performing the two tasks in separate steps:

<sup>Note: I know that your `Get-ChildItem` command will in practice only yield *1* file, but *potentially* it will yield *multiple* ones, so I'll try to solve that case.

Furthermore, I've avoided the use of `cmd.exe` variables (`%AppDate%`) and instead use only PowerShell's (`$env:AppData`).

Also, note the use of a *back-reference* (`\1`) in the regular expression below, which avoids the need to repeat `AdvertPlaceholder`, as well as the use of `$1` om the substitution expression to refer to the first capture group in the regex (`AdvertPlacholder`)</sup>

If we focus on just PowerShell for now, we get:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $env:AppData\Skype -Recurse config.xml
foreach($file in $files) { 
  (Get-Content $file.fullname) -replace '<(AdvertPlaceholder)>1</\1>', '<$1>0</$1>' |
    Set-Content $file.fullname
}
```

Note:

- In terms of character encoding, `Set-Content` defaults to system's default code page. When in doubt, use an explicit encoding, such as `-Encode UTF8`.
- The above assumes that the XML element in question is on a *single* line. If it isn't, things get more complicated: while you can use `Get-Content -Raw` (PowerShell v3+) to read the entire input file at once, `Set-Content` will add an *extra* newline to the output; also, you'd have to adapt the regex passed to `-replace` above to account for line-spanning whitespace.

  - [Matt's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34447673/45375) shows a more *robust* way of handling the value substitution, using proper XML parsing via the `[xml]` type (fully qualified name: `System.Xml.XmlDocument`).

If you still want to call the above PowerShell command from a *batch* file, here's how to do it:

Note the need to use a *single-line* literal to pass to `powershell.exe -command`, which makes the whole thing unreadable; also, adding `-noprofile` is generally a good idea so as to suppress loading of the profile file, which is intended only for *interactive* use.

```
 powershell -noprofile -command "$files = Get-ChildItem $env:AppData\Skype -Recurse config.xml; foreach($file in $files) { (Get-Content $file.fullname) -replace '<(AdvertPlaceholder)>1</\1>', '<$1>0</$1>' | Set-Content $file.fullname }"
```

Comment: I ended up using your approach since you do not exclude any other config.xml files, unlike @Matt. While currently there is only one config file in the folders under `...\Skype\...`, in case Skype ever gets more config files under different folders, even then the script will not break.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues and I think you are straying down an incorrect path. [Nathan Tuggy had one part right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446275/powershell-search-for-a-file-and-replace-a-string-inside-it#comment56635093_34446275), `Set-Content` takes pipeline input and sends it to file. The path of which, under most circumstances, needs to be specified with `-Path` (or positionally). Another issue that precedes that is you are not actually reading the file you located. Your current code is attempting to manipulate the file name itself, which is not what you want.

Something closer to what you are looking for would be:

```
powershell -Command "$file = Get-ChildItem %APPDATA%\Skype -Filter 'config.xml' -Recurse | Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName; (Get-Content $file) | ForEach-Object { $_.replace('<AdvertPlaceholder>1</AdvertPlaceholder>', '<AdvertPlaceholder>0</AdvertPlaceholder>')} | Set-Content $file"
```

I haven't tested that in batch perfectly mostly because I just wanted to try and show you where you were going wrong.

That gets the file name assuming there is only the one config.xml file in that directory structure. Use `-First 1` to ensure only one file name is returned. Then take that file name to feed into Get-Content to get the file. Then process the file in the loop to replace the text you want. Also used `.Replace()` instead of `-replace` as the latter supports regex and you are not.

I think, pending testing, that it would solve your issue.

---

However you are not editing an XML file it the most efficient and reliable way. You could also just have all this logic in a single PowerShell script. Lets look at that shall we:

```
# Append some loopback entries into the host file. Make sure you are running as admin else this would fail. 
"apps.skype.com","g.msn.com" | Foreach-Object{"127.0.0.1`t$_"} | Add-Content "$env:windir\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts"
# Beware that multiple executions of this would keep adding more entries as we do not check the existing ones. 

# Locate and read the config.xml document. Use object notation to find the node we need to change to 0 then save the file. 
$configPath = Get-Item "$($env:appdata)\Skype\*\config.xml" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $configPath)
$xml.config.UI.General.AdvertPlaceholder = "0"
$xml.Save($configPath)
```

If you need help runnning the script [here is a good post to get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script).

---

I figured only only config.xml was present. If you wanted to edit *all* config files then very little needs to change. This time though we need to be sure that the value you want to edit exits. Since config.xml is not a unique name.

```
# Locate and read the config.xml documents. Use object notation to find the node we need to change to 0 then save the file. 
$configPaths = Get-ChildItem "$($env:appdata)\Skype" -Filter "config.xml"  -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

# Cycle each file found
$configPaths | ForEach-Object{
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $_)
    if($xml.config.UI.General.AdvertPlaceholder){
        # Check to be sure this value actually is present before we try to change it. 
        $xml.config.UI.General.AdvertPlaceholder = "0"
        # Only need to save if change was made. 
        $xml.Save($_)
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give credit where it's due, your answer possesses far more detail when it comes to editing XML. Thank you!

Comment: @S.T.A.L.K.E.R. Updated the logic to allow for multiple files if you wanted. I only prevented this as I didn't expect there to be more than one skype config file but it is very likely there is more than one config file present and wanted to prevent errors.