# How to pass variable into powershell script through CFExecute arguments?

Tags: powershell, iis, coldfusion, cfexecute

I'm trying to pass a user supplied value into PowerShell script using the following code, but am having no luck:

```
<cfset MyVar="Woila!">

<cfoutput>
<cfexecute name="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" 

arguments="$MyVar = #MyVar# C:\Users\raimonds\Desktop\create_website_IIS_aws_uat_1.ps1" 
/>
</cfoutput>
```

The argument writes in the PowerShell command line, but it is not passing the variable into the .ps1 script with this syntax `$MyVar`.

Comment: As an aside, there is no need to wrap `<cfexecute>` tag in `<cfoutput>`. The CF variables inside the tag will be evaluated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
<cfexecute name="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" arguments="-file C:\Users\raimonds\Desktop\create_website_IIS_aws_uat_1.ps1 ""youvalue"""/>
```

Comment: Very strange but the second answer was correct with double quotes. Big thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Your were almost there. Just change the order, as follows:

```
<cfset MyVar="Woila!">

<cfexecute name="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" 

arguments="C:\Users\raimonds\Desktop\create_website_IIS_aws_uat_1.ps1 
 MyVar '#MyVar#'" />
```

Alternatively, define the *arguments* attribute as

```
arguments="& 'C:\Users\raimonds\Desktop\create_website_IIS_aws_uat_1.ps1' 
     MyVar '#MyVar#'"
```

This assumes your script defines the parameter MyVar in the usual way, for example:

```
 param([string]$MyVar)
```

See this [Stackoverflow page for additional Powershell options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script) you might want to use.