# This keeps doubling my output file!! how can i fix this?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

It keeps looking at your source file, then adding those changes to your output, since the source file doesn't change, it keeps adding those to the output

```
 $data = @(
        @{
            pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''logility_prod_scp_logility'',"
            replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''LOGILITY_PROD_SCP_LOGILITY'',"
            inputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_input1.ctg"
            outputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_output1.ctg"
        },
        @{
            pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''dwfei'',"
            replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''DW_FEI'',"
            inputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_output1.ctg"
            outputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_output2.ctg"
        },    
        @{
            pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''DWFEI'',"
            replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''DW_FEI'',"
            inputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_output2.ctg"
            outputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_output3.ctg"
        }

    )

    $data | 
        ForEach-Object  { 
            (Get-Content $_.inputFile) -replace $_.pattern, $_.replacement | Out-File $_.outputFile
        }
    I used above code..trying many other way's as well..how can i make sure my file sizes are not doubled?
```

I don't want my file to change size..all the above changes need's to be done on one output file only

Comment: LACTION 'SQL(''DWFEI'', ''BEGIN load_adj_hist_fact; END;'')'

Comment: My file has many contents in it...the part i  want to replace starts with LACTION 'SQL

Answer (score 1):

Does this produce the expected results?

```
$pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''DWFEI'',"
$replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''DW_FEI'',"
(Get-Content "inputfile.txt") -replace $pattern,$replacement |
  Out-File "newfile.txt"
```

Comment: (?) Just write out the new file, then replace the old file with the new one.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - You'll never get through to him without more exclamation marks...

Comment: i want to create an automation script for below commands.  This will run automatically and pick file based on variables declared?

Answer (score 0):

Put the script below in a PowerShell .ps1 file.

```
$data = @(
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''logility_prod_scp_logility'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''LOGILITY_PROD_SCP_LOGILITY'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_input.ctg"
        outPutFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_output.ctg"
    },
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''dwfei'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''DW_FEI'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_input.ctg"
        outPutFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_output.ctg"
    },    
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''DWFEI'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''DW_FEI'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_input.ctg"
        outputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_output.ctg"
    },
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''DWFEI'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''DW_FEI'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_input.ctg"
        outPutFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_output.ctg"

    },
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''dwfei'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''DW_FEI'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_input.ctg"
        outPutFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_output.ctg"
    },    
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''user_shared'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''USER_SHARED'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_input.ctg"
        outPutFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_output.ctg"

    },
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''DW_FEI_PROD'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''DW_FEI'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_input.ctg"
        outPutFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_output.ctg"
    },
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION'SQL\(''SALES_MART_PROD'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''SALES_MART'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_input.ctg"
        outPutFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_output.ctg"
    },    
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''sales_mart'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''SALES_MART'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_input.ctg"
        outPutFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_output.ctg"
    }
)

$data | 
    ForEach-Object  { 
        (Get-Content $_.inputFile) -replace $_.pattern, $_.replacement | Out-File $_.outputFile
    }
```

---

**Edit**

The `--Append` flag should be present on the `Out-File`.

```
$data | 
    ForEach-Object  { 
        (Get-Content $_.inputFile) -replace $_.pattern, $_.replacement | Out-File $_.outputFile --append
    }
```

**Edit**

If you are not familiar with PowerShell, the easiest way to run this script is via the steps below.

1. Copy/paste the PowerShell script in a file with name `script.ps1`.
2. Copy/paste the content below in a file with name `runscript.cmd`.

   ```
   @echo off
   SET psfile="%~dp0script.ps1"
   PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File %psfile%
   pause
   ```
3. Execute `runscript.cmd` from the command prompt.

Comment: @user9766188 When feedback is being given on your question, you are supposed to update your question, not an answer. But no problem, we all here to learn. If the answer gives is a solution to your question you can accept otherwise you give feedback via a comment.

Comment: @user9766188 Please explain.

Comment: The code is fine, but PowerShell commands can't be executed directly from a DOS/Windows command prompt. You either save the script in a file with extension .ps1 and execute that one, or the easiest way is to execute it via a GUI tool like PowerShell ISE. Search on this site on [how to execute a PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script).

Comment: @user9766188 Updated answer with how to run a PowerShell script, but please do some research.

Comment: That is as expected as you configured the outputFile '"C:\files\SALES_MART_output.ctg" to be used for each inputFile.

Comment: Use a different output file for each item in the array, like outPutFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_output1.ctg", outPutFile = "C:\files\SALES_MART_output2.ctg", ect.

Comment: This keeps failing Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\files\DW_FEI_input.ctg' because it does not exist.

Comment: added image to this post