# Powershell Automation script using below commands that updates at one shot

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

My script works fine and does changes as required. Only issue it does is my input file size remains same and output file keeps doubling. How can i stop that? Input is my orginal file!! when i compare i can see changes but my output ctg files gets doubled!! please help

```
$data = @(
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''logility_prod_scp_logility'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''LOGILITY_PROD_SCP_LOGILITY'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_input.ctg"
        outputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_output.ctg"
    },
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''dwfei'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''DW_FEI'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_input.ctg"
        outputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_output.ctg"
    },    
    @{
        pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''DWFEI'',"
        replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''DW_FEI'',"
        inputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_input.ctg"
        outputFile = "C:\files\DW_FEI_output.ctg"
    }

)

$data | 
    ForEach-Object  { 
        (Get-Content $_.inputFile) -replace $_.pattern, $_.replacement | Out-File $_.outputFile
    }
```

Comment: Save your commands in a `.ps1` file and then run the script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can we automate below commands. Is there a efficient way to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471182/how-can-we-automate-below-commands-is-there-a-efficient-way-to-do-it)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart It is a duplicate.

Comment: Correct. The "possible" wording is added automatically by the system when you flag the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Today, you're running this process to swap a series of tokens out in your source `.ctg` file.  I would propose moving each of the steps into lines in a `.CSV` file like so:

```
#This
$pattern = "LACTION 'SQL\(''logility_prod_scp_logility'',"
$replacement = "LACTION 'SQL(''LOGILITY_PROD_SCP_LOGILITY'',"
```

We would move these two strings into columns within a `.CSV` file, like below.  A note, since there are a *lot* of commas in your fields, I would recommend using a semicolon instead:

```
Source;Target
"LACTION 'SQL\(''logility_prod_scp_logility'',";"LACTION 'SQL(''LOGILITY_PROD_SCP_LOGILITY'',"
```

We can retrieve these values like so:

```
$strings | convertfrom-csv -Delimiter ';'
```

#### Integration

First, you should manually move all of your tokens from those nine steps into a semicolon separated value list.

Secondly, once you've done this, you can iterate through each line in the `.CSV` to replace all of the tokens with just six lines.

```
$string = Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Path c:\PathTo\YourFile.csv
ForEach($string in $strings){

   (Get-Content "C:\files\DW_FEI_DEV_input.ctg") -replace $string.Source,$string.Target |
      Out-File "C:\files\DW_FEI_DEV_output.ctg"

}
```

Comment: Can you provide me an example! This looks confusing I can only update in CTg file i beileve not in csv file that is my requirement