# Powershell copy-item from text file

Tags: powershell

Hoping someone can help.

I have in a text file 100's of lines that copy and pastes files.

```
Copy-Item "Source\File123.txt" -Destination "Destination\Folder123"
Copy-Item "Source\File542.txt" -Destination "Destination\Folder542"
Copy-Item "Source\File567.txt" -Destination "Destination\Folder567"
```

How can I get powershell to execute each of these lines by loading the text file.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script

Answer (score 0):

```
get-content C:\scripts\garbage.txt | % {Invoke-Command $([ScriptBlock]::Create("$_"))}
```

...But this raises the question.. how did you end up with a txt file with the commands actually in it..? Would be much easier if the file just had source & destination in them.