# Powershell in SQL Management Studio

Tags: powershell, ssms

Cannot run ps scripts in SSMS, Receiving the error :

The term 'c:\myfolder\test.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

command i ran was

exec xp_cmdshell 'powershell "c:\myfolder\test.ps1"'

the script does exist in that location.

Comment: Try `exec xp_cmdshell powershell.exe -file c:\myfolder\test.ps1'`

Comment: You need to run it against the powershell.exe command line. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script/2035209