# Run PowerShell script with spaces in the file path

Tags: powershell, shell, batch-file

I cannot get the following batch code to work if variable `!batDir!` contains spaces, e.g. `W:\scripts windows\`:

```
if /I "!i!" GTR "1" (
        Powershell "!batDir!ript.ps1 !test! '!testWithSpaces!' "
        goto :scriptEnd
)

W:\scripts : The term 'W:\scripts' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program.
```

Comment: Have you tried `'!batDir!ript.ps1'`, i.e. single quotes around the filepath, like with `'!testWithSpaces!'`?

Comment: Then I got an error `Unexpected token '-filter' in expression or statement.` The variable !test! is -filter.

Comment: I think that means that the path has qualified as OK. I would suggest to `echo` the expression first before you pass it to Powershell to debug.

Comment: `Powershell "'W:\scrips windows\ript.ps1' -filter 'unity*' "`

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script/2035209) to run PS from CMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use quotes with &.

```
Powershell "& '!batDir!ript.ps1' !test! '!testWithSpaces!' "
```

https://newbedev.com/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-with-white-spaces-in-path-from-command-line