# How can i run a powershell script from a batch file as admin to join a domain?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, azure-active-directory, windows-10

I am trying to run this from a .cmd with run as administrator

```bash
powershell -Command "&{ Start-Process powershell Add-Computer -Domain "domain.domain" -Credential login -Verb RunAs -Wait -Confirm}"
```

The window to input password does pop up, but after I input the password I am greeted with the following error on my batch script.

```
Start-Process : O conjunto de parâmetros não pode ser resolvido usando os parâmetros nomeados especificados.
No linha:1 caractere:4
+ &{ Start-Process powershell Add-Computer -Domain domain.domain -Cr ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I want to join a domain via scripting, I tried to use netdom, but it's exclusive to servers. I am dealing with client notebooks with Windows 10, very far from the server, and I don't have any admin access to the server domai. I am just formatting a huge amount of computers to a specified state, and that includes joining then on a domain. I don't care how I join the domain as long as I join the domain automatically, (if impossible asking for password is acceptable), from a batch or powershell script, and without instaling anything.

Comment: Also note the owner-only join hardening since the october 2022 update:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5020276-netjoin-domain-join-hardening-changes-2b65a0f3-1f4c-42ef-ac0f-1caaf421baf8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using this following in a .cmd file:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -noexit "& ""C:\your\path\to\domainjoinscript.ps1"""
```

from

> [How to run a PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script)

The `-executionpolicy bypass` flag is because by default, PowerShell doesn't let you run un-trusted scripts (even if you created them). Either you have to disable the Execution Policy system-wide, or do it like this.

Your `.ps1` file should contain:

```
add-computer -domainname "yourdomain" -restart
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem, now i run in another problem... just before i run this script i change the computer name with this...
...
set /P newname="what is the computer name? "
wmic computersystem where name='%computername%' call rename name='%newname%'
...
But i can not join domain because the previous name is still in use... do you know some way i can bypass the need to do two computer restarts? one for rename and one for the domain?

Comment: $env:computername has the computername.  You should be able to rename and join in one reboot like in the control panel, but I've had trouble with it.  Is -noexit necessary?  Won't you need domain credentials?