# PowerShell - How to use a script without the path to work in the current path?

Tags: powershell

I apologize in advance, I'm not entirely sure the best way to word my question. Here's what I'm trying to do...

I created a script called `beginPHP.ps1` which is located in my `c:\users\USERNAME\scripts` directory.

I added said directory with `$env:path += c:\users\USERNAME\scripts` and it shows when I do `$env:path`. I also made sure it shows in my `Environment Variables` (and `System Variables`) per [This Link](https://www.imatest.com/docs/editing-system-environment-variables/#Windows).

I opened my PowerShell (v7) and went to the directory I wanted the script to `RUN` in (not where it's located). In this case `C:\xampp\htdocs\wip`. Running the command `beginPHP` gives me the following error:

```
beginPHP: The term 'beginPHP' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Here's what I'm looking for --
What am I missing in order to be able to just type in a script name and have it run at the current `-Path`?

I did check [how-to-run-a-powershell-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script), but that needs you in the location the script is located. I hope to use this script more than once in more than one location (or I wouldn't bother creating it).

/*******************************************************/

FYI - running `c:\users\USERNAME\scripts\beginPHP` did work, so the script is functional. I'm still trying to figureo out how to NOT need the path everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```bash
$newPath = 'c:\users\USERNAME\scripts'
$targetEnv = [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User # or `::Machine`

[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(
    'Path',
    @([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $targetEnv).Split(
        [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator,
        [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
        $newPath) -join [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator,
    $targetEnv)
```

The problem is that storing the path in [`$env:Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.3#path-information) doesn't persist across sessions. If you want it to persist, you can use [`[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=net-7.0). You could also consider turning your `ps1` into a `psm1` and using a Module instead.

Comment: Tried it with both `::User` and `::Machine` - neither work - same error when I try and run `beginPHP`

Comment: I lied - I'm an idiot - I wasn't restarting `PS` - restarted `PS` and it works perfectly.

Comment: @jpgerb yeah forgot to mention you need to restart your current session to have it available, my bad :P

Comment: What's sad is I knew that too - just totally forgot. Kind of glad I forgot if the $env:path would just reset anyway. At least now I have it in my SystemEnvVar