# Is there a way to configure Visual Studio to open a console application on Windows Terminal using Powershell?

Tags: visual-studio

I have Windows Terminal configured to open Powershell as the default profile.  This works as expected when launching WT manually.

I am working on a console application using Visual Studio that needs to use Powershell capabilities.  The problem is that it launches WT with a command prompt tab rather than Powershell.

I googled a bunch and failed to find a configuration method.  ChatGPT suggested pointing the appropriate configuration to "wt.exe".  That didn't work (it launches cmd prompt, which then launches wt.exe and it doesn't know what to do from there).

Any thoughts?

Edit:

I appears I wasn't clear.  I want Visual Studio to open WT with this:

[image: Windows Terminal with Powershell tab]

Not this (which it what it does):

[image: Windows Terminal with Command Prompt]

Both of the above are screenshots of Windows Terminal.

[image: Windows Terminal: About]

Which is configured to launch Powershell by default:

[image: Windows Terminal Startup Configuration]

Visual Studio launches Windows Terminal just fine, except that it does not launch it with the default Powershell profile.

I would like Visual Studio to simply use the default WT, as configured, for all console projects.

Comment: `needs to use Powershell capabilities` what does that mean? The question shows quite a bit of confusion between terminals (Windows Terminal or Console), shells (PowerShell, PowerShell Core, CMD) and processes (any application). A process doesn't need a shell like PowerShell or CMD to run. Visual Studio starts the process and attaches a *terminal* to it directly, not a shell. If you want to use *shell* functionality you have to start a shell with either `pwsh.exe` for PowerShell Core or `cmd` for CMD and have it start the process

Comment: `ChatGPT suggested` that's because ChatGPT isn't smart. It's a statistical text generator whose output depends on the *question* as well as the statistical distribution of the data it was trained on. If the question confused terminals and shells, the answer would do the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug a Windows PowerShell module in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298963/how-do-i-debug-a-windows-powershell-module-in-visual-studio). In short, try `pwsh.exe -Command "path-to-my.exe"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56753339/how-to-use-the-new-windows-terminal-as-visual-studio-debugging-console